# Range = Range.Value method to transfer visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am aware of the copy and paste visible cells method (as below) however, i was hoping to use the same method using a range = range.SpecialCells(xlVisible). is this possible?

```
    Sub tstsa()
        Dim lastrow As Long
        With Sheets2
        lastrow = .Range("Q1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:Q" & lastrow).Cells.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy
        End With
        Sheet8.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible or not, but if it was possible, you would need to know how many rows of visible cells there were, which, depending on your needs, might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: You can't use (eg) `a.Value = b.Value` on multi-area ranges

Comment: @padawan0007 - The preferred (?) parameter to use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) is [xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) but in reality, both `xlCellTypeVisible ` and `xlVisible` resolve to **12**. Try it in the VBE's Immediate window as `?xlCellTypeVisible` and `?xlVisible `.

Comment: It's possible but not the way you are doing it. You would have to iterate through the visible cells and direct transfer the [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or [Range.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection in [Range.SpecialCells(](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx)[xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx)) is a collection of [Range.Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx). This is akin to what you receive with a [.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) of discontiguous cells.

```
Sub tstsa()
    Dim rws As Long
    With Sheet2
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Cells
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 17)
                Debug.Print .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(0, 0)
                Sheet8.Range("a1:q1") = .Rows(1).Cells.Value2
                For rws = 2 To .SpecialCells(xlVisible).Areas.Count
                    Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(1, 17) = _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(rws).Cells.Value2
                Next rws
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

In your case, the Areas will be the visible rows of filtered data (including the header). You need to loop through the Areas and bring the [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or [Range.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) property across to Sheet8 for direct value transfer.

An Area can consist of more than one row of data if the rows are contiguous. I've left a `Debug.Print` in so you can observe the address of the Areas collection in the VBE's Immediate window.